# iPython notebook: error when importing pygraphviz

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz, pygraphviz

When I try to import pygraphviz like this

```
import graphviz
import pygraphviz
```

As a first go, I get this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3b2d04bd6813> in <module>()
      1 import graphviz
----> 2 import pygraphviz

...

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/<user>/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/./libcgraph.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/<user>/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so
  Reason: image not found
```

And rerunning the same cell (and doing nothing in between) gives another error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-3b2d04bd6813> in <module>()
      1 import graphviz
----> 2 import pygraphviz
      3 
      4 G = pygraphviz.AGraph(directed=True)
      5 G.add_nodes_from(range(1,9))

/Users/<user>/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygraphviz/__init__.py in <module>()
     30 
     31 # Release data
---> 32 from . import release
     33 
     34 if release.revision is None:

ImportError: cannot import name 'release'
```

Checking my dependencies with `pip show [options] <package>` checks out. They are both in my /anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages lib.

I've installed both with pip install. Also, I've tried to reinstall several times.

Any ideas are welcome..

Comment: Can you import it from a regular `.py` file, running it with `python foo.py`? i.e. is it specifically a problem when using IPython, or does the import not work at all?

Comment: @Thomas K. Running python in a terminal and using import pygraphviz, I get a different error: _ImportError: dlopen(/Users/<user>/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/./libcgraph.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/<user>/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so
  Reason: image not found_

Comment: That looks very much like the first error you got.